# How to record movie clips of run sessions in Vugen with IE10

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner, vugen

[image: How to record movie clips of run sessions in Vugen with IE10]

I have recorded the script in Vugen with IE10. While running the script in replay mode it shows script failed. Viewing the failed script, it shows the message as

> To better understand the cause of failed steps, you can record movie clips of run sessions and view them together with the step result details.

Hereby attached doc for reference. Please anyone help on this!

Thanks,
Sakthirajan Kathirvel

Comment: The error seems a bit vague. Could you please tell the version of VuGen. Additionally, the versions before 12.53 may not support the recording of all forms of video files. However, in 12.53, HP as instituted some changes to support video recording. You could check that out too. [link](http://community.hpe.com/t5/LoadRunner-Information-and-News/LoadRunner-12-53-Released/td-p/6859419)

Answer (score 0):

This is a resource you may want to consult related to the testing of "streaming" media

http://www.perfbytes.com/streaming-performance